# Filter groupType works on groups but not on memberOf

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I can get all unified groups from azure active directory quite easily, especially cause it is explicitly mentioned within [the documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter-parameter):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?filter=groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified')
```

And you can get all groups a user belongs to with [this query](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_memberof):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/memberOf
```

Now lets combine those two queries to get all unified groups a user belongs to:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/memberOf?filter=groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified')
```

and you'll get back:

```
HTTP Status Code 400
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Filter not supported.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "{request-id}",
            "date": "2018-07-06T07:29:52"
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, so groups supports lambda query, so let's expand on that and enhance the filter to also filter on members:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified') and members/any(u:u/id+eq+'{user-id}')
```

But this returns

```
HTTP Status Code 400
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "Unsupported Query.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "{request-id}",
            "date": "2018-07-06T07:41:47"
        }
    }
}
```

So, why isn't any of this supported (also not in beta)?

Answer (score 1):

Please try using the below query to get all unified groups a user belongs to -

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/{user-id}/memberOf/$/microsoft.graph.group?$filter=groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified')
```

Answer (score 1):

> So, why isn't any of this supported (also not in beta)?

$filter is not supported by [List memberOf Rest API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_memberof). We could get that information from [List memberOf Rest API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_memberof) document.

> This method supports the OData Query Parameters to help customize the response. **$filter** is **not** **supported**.

From [List Group Rest API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list), we could know that there no any properties related to user.
So you try to  filter on members is not supported.

As SaurabhSharma-MSFT mentioned that you could use following way to do that.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/{user-id}/memberOf/$/microsoft.graph.group?$filter=groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified')
```